# PhantomJS Webserver exe on Azure Web Role Startup

Tags: azure, phantomjs, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to launch a local webserver instance of PhantomJs on a Azure Web (or Worker) Role to use with HighCharts for rendering server side charting images.

PhantomJs comes as just a simple `.exe` that can be launched as a webserver with the following command:

`phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3003`

... and then local HTTP POST requests can be made against it.

I have included this command in a `startup.cmd` batch script that is configured to execute with my Azure Web Role when published via `ServiceDefinition.csdef`:

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
</Startup>
```

startup.cmd:

```
START phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3003

EXIT /B 0
```

From what I can tell, this appears to execute fine on startup, however, the process does not stay running. It just executes and closes. For example, I can remote into the box, find the deployment and execute `startup.cmd` manually (in which a command window opens and stays open), and everything works fine.

How do I execute the PhantomJs exe webserver upon instance startup to where it continues running and does not close?

I have tried setting `taskType` to `simple` and `background` in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` declaration, yet it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I did not have the supporting `.js` files set to "Copy To Output Directory", so the `startup.cmd` could not find them.

Thanks to Steve for the output logging suggestion, which allowed me to see the error that it could not find "highcharts-convert.js".

Comment: How's your experience been with starting PhantomJS as a webserver?  I've been creating a new c# process that starts PhantomJS and I'm looking at going your route to try and improve performance.  It looks like PhantomJS still marks this as "experimental"
http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/

Comment: Been using it for several months now for a nightly job. No problems.

Comment: Have you had any issues with the PhantomJS process getting bogged down?  Do you know how to restart the PhantomJS process without doing a full role-recycle?  I have a azure endpoint that is pinging the status of the phantomjs server, but I'm not sure how to restart PhantomJS without a full vm restart if something were to go wrong.

Comment: I have not had to deal with that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a timing issue if it is executing.  You could add something like:

```
 ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 300000 > nul
```

before you execute the script.

You could also pipe out to a log file so if its executing you can see what it is doing.  >> log.txt.

If its not executing I would probably look at the path given its executing in the background and not interactively.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a timing issue or what the ping would do to alleviate that. Could you explain? I added some logging to `startup.cmd` to confirm that it executes on startup. It does. I also piped logging of the phantomjs.exe call to the log and it did not log anything for that line.

Comment: I had issues with something similar where a dependency hadn't started so like you if I ran it afterwards perfect but if the start-up ran exactly the same thing it called it but it didn't complete as the box was still bringing everything up.  The ping is essentially a pause while other services start-up and in my case Websites and my application was configured.

Comment: I don't know phantom, where does it log to.  Presumably you see output on the screen if run interactively?

Comment: Tried the ping delay, didn't seem to help. I do see screen output when I run the exe manually. I'm guessing that should be logged if I pipe out the START command?

Comment: I removed the `START` and was able to get some logged output from calling the .exe. This allowed me to find the problem. See my posted answer. Thanks!